# Where to see all tag wiki edits?

Tags: support, tag-wiki, edits

Is it possible to view tag wiki edits done by myself?

I currently don't see this kind of functionality anywhere, not also in the profile. Am I missing something?

#### Note

I have searched the meta, but I didn't find anything in this reference.

Comment: You can see [all your suggested edits on your profile](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1135954/mtk?tab=activity&sort=suggestions), but not specifically tag wiki edits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's a dedicated section for it. You can, however, go to *Activity* tab in your profile, and then go to either *suggestions* if you suggested those wiki edits, or *revisions* if you had enough reputation to just edit them. You will be able to find your tag wiki activity there.

You could also try making a query at [data.stackexchange.com](https://data.stackexchange.com/) to get that info, but I'm totally ignorant about how data.SE.com works, so can't help you on that one.